# SD Maid installed service - Is it actually useful and doesn't take up much battery?

Tags: applications, battery, cleanup

I found out about the app's installed service, I'm not sure if it would take up more battery by enabling it to clean memory and stop apps. Has anyone found this installed service useful? Will it unexpectedly close apps like sleep cycle that acts as an alarm and snore recorder overnight?

Comment: @beeshyams Yes, under that is installed services. Do you know if it actually helps in clearing up RAM properly, and therefore saving battery? If you played pokemon go, does it conflict with adventure sync by forcing the game to stop?

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'm not referring to app cleaner as that is a PRO option only. I apologize for the ambiguity as I'm not quite sure how SD Maid works exactly, but it doesn't seem to freeze Pokemon go at the least. What I'm concerned about is adventure sync, which tracks your Km distance walked despite not having the app opened, it syncs based on your location and where you go. I was just not sure if the game actually does work in the background for adventure sync to work or something when the game is not launched, but I'm assuming SD Maid won't interfere with that.

Comment: @beeshyams
In case you are wondering, this is what I meant: https://imgur.com/a/DNBxMSl
I did not find anything where it asks me to "force stop" apps, so I have no idea how it really works. It seems to clean RAM at random times at most for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131603/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-shangwang).